# Is jQuery .text() method XSS safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

I have unescaped data from users.

So is it safe to use like this:

```
var data = '<test>a&f"#</test>'; // example data from ajax response
if (typeof(data) === 'string')
    $('body').text(data);
```

Can I use like this or there is some problems like encoding or some specific symbols that I should be careful and add more strict validation?

Comment: Even though jQuery effectively escapes HTML elements when using `.text(data)`, something can be said for not having completely unescaped user defined HTML in your database at all. You should not have to trust your memory to use client side HTML escaping every time you use that database variable and neither should anyone ever using your code.  
So I'd say, strip the html tags from the data before saving it to your database. Have some tests that ensure you can only save html stripped data for user defined fields. I don't really see the value of escaping vs. stripping in this case.

Comment: If user wants send html I don't want say to him sorry bro you can't. Maybe that is not html how should i know? whats wrong with saving in database not sanitized data? Why should I delete some parts or modify user data? If I do then how user will be able get his data exactly he submitted?

Comment: It's not about refusing to store dangerous data, it's about making dangerous data safe to store and use. Not many people will try to legitimately use HTML and those who do will see that their HTML is stripped soon enough. Stripping the html tags around text will still leave the text inside them.

You really have to modify user data that if that data can be dangerous to you and others. Don't leave it around in your database to be used accidentally.

Comment: If stackoverflow would save data as you say we wont be able to show html code in questions and answers..

Comment: If user posted that data he thinks he will be able to get it exactly same as posted not with stripped tags or something... am I wrong?

Comment: Ok that's a case where escaping is more useful than stripping. That does not take away that you should save your data in the database in a safe (stripped or escaped) form.

Comment: striping thing is really annoying.. Example on some blog comments someone wants to show example of html code and site is stripping html code user have to use  `[]` instead  of `<>` or  something.. That really annoys me. If user user posted that, then it should be displayed as it is.. am I wrong?

Comment: @JornvandeBeek: I have to disagree with you. If you are getting html tags in data where you don't want it, you should reject that data instead of making it safe. So no stripping. If however you are receiving data where anything is allowed, you need to escape it. But you cannot decide how to escape it when storing it in the database, because XSS defense depends on context. See the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet.

Comment: I just newer needed that if data is some username or something that is  allowing just some characters then I add validation and inform user about error.. but in other cases user can post what he wants I don't understand why should I remove that if user wants to post that? As long as I showing data correctly.. Or you have to inform user that data like `< something here>` will be deleted

Answer (score 60, accepted):

When you set the text of an element using the `text` method, jQuery uses `createTextNode` internally, which escapes all special characters.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method `.createTextNode()`, which replaces special characters
>   with their HTML entity equivalents (such as `&lt;` for `<`)

So yes, it should be safe. Here's [your example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLu69/). Notice how the tags appear as literal text.

Comment: Note that this function also does the reverse - so calling it on already escaped data will result in it being unescaped which can inadvertently result in an XSS - E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/7ykbosas/1/

Comment: Minor point of order, `createTextNode` does *not* "escape all special characters". You're already telling the browser that this is inert text, it doesn't have to escape anything, it simply doesn't run it through any code paths that could possibly execute anything.

Answer (score 15):

Because XSS attacks rely on being able to insert DOM nodes (`<img />`, `<script />`) etc, and `jQuery.fn.text()` does not support this, it is entirely XSS safe.

As you can see in this [basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/XBYxu/), all would-be-HTML tags are encoded as a result of jQuery using `createTextNode` internally:

```
jQuery('div').text('<test>a&f"#</test>');​
```

So that what is *actually* inserted is more equivilant to;

```
jQuery('div').html('&lt;test&gt;a&f"#&lt;/test&gt;');​
```

Answer (score 8):

You still have to be careful when inserting the result into the DOM - see: [Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability with JavaScript and JQuery](http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/cross-site-scripting-vulnerability-with-javascript-and-jquery/).

For setting the text of elements, however, text should be XSS safe.

Comment: +1 This is quite important and often overlooked. To summarize : `JQuery text() returns unescaped payload which can result in the execution of malicious script if it's passed on to .after() or append() etc. methods`

Answer (score 1):

The author from http://benv.ca/2012/10/02/you-are-probably-misusing-DOM-text-methods/ argues against using `createTextNode` or jQuery's `.text()`.

> ...if you know the context in which you are injecting the value (i.e. not attributes), then this method is safe. My argument is that developers don’t understand those contexts well enough, and sooner or later they will get it wrong.

It is better to use string replacement (of at least `<`).

Some examples from well-secured libraries:

- Mustache https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L55
- Angular https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L438

The [#1 OWASP suggestion](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) is:

> RULE #1 - HTML Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Element Content

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
>   documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the
>   combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
>   parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
>   and other white space.)

`.text(data)` would strip the `<test></test>` away and leave you with `a&f#`

Comment: text not stripping anything just escaping so the result would be `&lt;test&gt;a&f"#&lt;/test&gt;`

Comment: do you have a proof for that ? Because I have used .text() many many many times and it always worked for me.

Comment: Okay, than this only works for real jQuery Objects to extract the text from the elements.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It deals in text, not code.