# create a href tag with query string for a dynamic html tag inside a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a href tag with a query string, the href tag is concatenated with the other html tags generated dynamically through Javascript code, all the code is inside .js file.

```
for (var k = 0; k < member.length; k++) {

        var selectedMember = member[k].memberid;
        var htmlth = "";
        htmlth = "<tr>" + "<th colspan='4'>" + member[k].membername + "</th>"+
            "<th colspan='2'>" + "<a href='Update.php?memberid= member[k].memberid  '>" +
            'Update' + "</a>" + "</th>" +"</tr>" 

        tableHtml.append(htmlth);
```

the above code doesn't work as href considers member[k].memberid value as string, how do I write member[k].memberid value inside  tag and assign to href

Comment: `href` is an attribute of an anchor tag, `a`. As far as your question goes, you're outputting the `member[k].membername` value within the `th` tag; do something similar for the `member[k].memberid` value.

Comment: You didn't close your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an elegant JQuery implementation you can try this:

```js
let members = [
    {
        memberid: 1, 
        membername: 'jake'
    },
    {
        memberid: 2,
        membername: 'clement'
    },
    {
        memberid: 3, 
        membername: 'kelvin'
    }
];

let table = $('<table></table>');
for(var k = 0; k < members.length; k++) {
    const selectedMember = members[k];
    let htmlth = $(
        "<tr>" + 
            "<th colspan='4'>" +
                selectedMember.membername +
            "</th>" +
            "<th colspan='2'>" +
                "<a href='Update.php?memberid=" + selectedMember.memberid + "'>" +
                    "Update" +
                "</a>" +
            "</th>" +
        "</tr>"
    );
    table.append(htmlth);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append(table);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <title>My test doc</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>welcome</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, see the Fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/udochify/mtzndxgu/)

I included the array of objects to give you a complete running code.

The problem with your code is that you included `member[k].memberid` inside the string quotation marks. Also, you should have used the `selectedMember` variable you created earlier to access `memberid` and `membername`.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the detailed explanation.

Comment: Future viewers should take care to note that like the code in the initial question, this solution is extremely vulnerable to XSS through the `membername` attribute.

Comment: @IronFlare, XSS prevention should be a facility provided when getting the data input from the user, not necessarily when processing it as in this case. Here, the `membername` can be from the server side as well as from the user. So, I had to abstract that functionality "away" from my answer so that it is directly targeted at the question  and clearer.  However, the answer you provided is ok. For other ways of preventing XSS using jQuery see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735045/is-jquery-text-method-xss-safe) and (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590792/prevent-xss-in-jquery-html)

Comment: @UdoE. I understand your perspective. I think that it's foolish to rely on the server alone for XSS protection when a mixed server- and client-side solution is much more robust. Given that the asker's initial code is trivially susceptible to an XSS attack, I think it's safe to assume their database is also not protected, and should be assumed to already contain malicious entries. jQuery does have utilities to mitigate this, but they're quite ineffective when not used in the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with PHP specifically but it's just a simple url parameter so I'll assume it works the same as other frameworks. Have you tried terminating the string before the variable and restarting the string after it?

```
"<a href='Update.php?memberid=' + member[k].memberid + '>"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, this has nothing to do with php here. + member[k].memberid + is value is not accessible inside , this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to terminate the string and concatenate the variable using `+`, but this code is highly vulnerable to XSS (Cross-Site scripting) in its current state. If a user can manipulate their `membername` to contain `<script>alert(1);</script>`, they could execute arbitrary client-side code for anyone who loads it.

I previously wrote an answer that used `document.createElement`, `cloneNode` to prevent XSS, but because this is only a small part of the asker's code, they requested I simplify it to allow them to add more columns later on. With this in mind, here is a modified version which still protects against XSS, but uses `innerHTML` to define the structure of the template row and classes to target the elements that use untrusted user data.

```
let t_row = document.createElement("tr");
t_row.innerHTML = "<th class='mname' colspan='4'></th><th colspan='2'><a class='mupdate'>Update</a></th>";

for (var k = 0; k < member.length; k++) {
    let selectedMember = member[k].memberid;
    let curr_row = t_row.cloneNode(true);

    curr_row.querySelector('.mname').textContent = member[k].membername;
    curr_row.querySelector('.mupdate').setAttribute("href",`Update.php?memberid=${selectedMember}`);

    tableHtml.appendChild(curr_row);
    // ...
}
```

You can see this code running [here](https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/u1f3gk6b/10/).

Comment: Thank you for your time and the response. Tried the code you posted earlier, appendChild to be modified to append and then the code works, can you please suggest if we can do in a way as I posted in my question rather using document.createElement and appending everything bcoz I have complex rows in my further code.

Comment: Yes, I can, but there will be some degree of compromise to prevent XSS. It's definitely easier in the short-term to just append raw HTML code, but the [risk of someone abusing that](https://gomakethings.com/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks-when-using-innerhtml-in-vanilla-javascript/) is extremely high. I'll modify my answer and then tag you.

Comment: @Kavya I overhauled the code to allow you to add additional columns more easily. Instead of placing the user's `membername` directly in the HTML, I have used classes to target the elements within each row and add data as text; this won't render as HTML and is thus not vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: @Kavya My pleasure. If my response answered your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons.